# dictionary and list comprehension in R

Tags: r, list, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Any generic way of doing the following R code faster? For example in python dict comprehension (see equivalent below) would be a nice faster alternative.

R:

```
l1 <- 1:3
l2 <- c("a", "b", "c")
foo <- function(x) {return(5*x)}
bar <- list()
for (i in 1:length(l1)) bar[l2[i]] <- foo(l1[i])
```

Python

```
l1 = range(1, 4)
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
def foo(x):
    return 5*x
{b: foo(a) for a, b in zip(l1, l2)}
```

Comment: `setNames(lapply(l1,foo),l2)`.

Comment: If you don't need it as a list (because it's just one number per element), you could use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

Comment: Since multiplication (and thus `foo`) is vectorized, you can just do `as.list(setNames(l1 * 5, l2))` or `as.list(setNames(foo(l1), l2))`; drop the `as.list` to keep it as a named numeric vector.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're talking about speed, so let's do some benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(op = {for (i in 1:length(l1)) bar[l2[i]] <- foo(l1[i])},
               lapply = setNames(lapply(l1,foo),l2),
               vectorised = setNames(as.list(foo(l1)), l2))

Unit: microseconds
       expr   min    lq     mean median     uq    max neval
         op 7.982 9.122 10.81052  9.693 10.548 36.206   100
     lapply 5.987 6.557  7.73159  6.842  7.270 55.877   100
 vectorised 4.561 5.132  6.72526  5.417  5.987 80.964   100
```

But these small values don't mean much, so I pumped up the vector length to 10,000 where you'll really see a difference:

```
l <- 10000
l1 <- seq_len(l)
l2 <- sample(letters, l, replace = TRUE)

microbenchmark(op = {bar <- list(); for (i in 1:length(l1)) bar[l2[i]] <- foo(l1[i])},
               lapply = setNames(lapply(l1,foo),l2),
               vectorised = setNames(as.list(foo(l1)), l2),
               times = 100)

Unit: microseconds
       expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
         op 30122.865 33325.788 34914.8339 34769.8825 36721.428 41515.405   100
     lapply 13526.397 14446.078 15217.5309 14829.2320 15351.933 19241.767   100
 vectorised   199.559   259.997   349.0544   296.9155   368.614  3189.523   100
```

But tacking onto what everyone else said, it doesn't have to be a list. If you remove the list requirement:

```
microbenchmark(setNames(foo(l1), l2))

Unit: microseconds
                  expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
 setNames(foo(l1), l2) 22.522 23.8045 58.06888 25.0875 48.322 1427.417   100
```